# calculate mean for each gamble and create a new column

Tags: r, mean

I want to calculate mean of reward for each gamble and create a new column based on that. for example, this is my data:

```
 gamble<-c(1,2,3,4,2,3,4,1)
 reward <- c(1,0.5,0.5,0.4,0.5,0.4,0.2,0.5)
 new<-data.frame(gamble, reward)
```

and the new column should look like this:

```
gamble reward newcolumn
   1    1.0      0.75
   2    0.5      0.50
   3    0.5      0.45
   4    0.4      0.30
   2    0.5      0.50
   3    0.4      0.45
   4    0.2      0.30
   1    0.5      0.75
```

thank you very much in advance... i am really confused...

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with a very big data base, and you're concerned really about time, then data.table approach is a very good option:

```
> library(data.table)
> DT <- data.table(new)
> DT[, newColumn:=mean(reward), by=gamble]
> DT
   gamble reward newColumn
1:      1    1.0      0.75
2:      2    0.5      0.50
3:      3    0.5      0.45
4:      4    0.4      0.30
5:      2    0.5      0.50
6:      3    0.4      0.45
7:      4    0.2      0.30
8:      1    0.5      0.75
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic question, and you can probably find many examples here on SO. In base R, you can use `ave` to get the output you're looking for.

```
> new$newColumn <- with(new, ave(reward, gamble, FUN = mean))
> new
  gamble reward newColumn
1      1    1.0      0.75
2      2    0.5      0.50
3      3    0.5      0.45
4      4    0.4      0.30
5      2    0.5      0.50
6      3    0.4      0.45
7      4    0.2      0.30
8      1    0.5      0.75
```

In this case, `FUN = mean` is optional since that is the default function used by `ave`; I've included it just so you can see that it is possible to add other aggregation functions.

Unlike many of the other aggregation functions (`aggregate`, `tapply`, and so on), the output of `ave` is the same length as its input.

Comment: Or simply `within(new, newColumn <- ave(reward, gamble))`.

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft, Just curious: what are you trying to point out with your comment? `within`? That one doesn't need to specify `mean` when using `ave`?